# Deploy Node server that isn't a web application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created a Node server that receives events through webhooks, handles them, and posts their data to one API endpoint. Currently I'm deploying it using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, but I don't know if it's the best option.

1. I don't need load balancers.
2. I don't need web servers like Apache/Nginx.
3. My Node server does not have any ports to receive requests, since it's a simple server that only handles webhooks events. So the EBS service will always be without metrics for requests (severe health status - because doesn't handle any of the health requests).

Should I use another type of AWS service? Docker?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I went for it with the App Runner AWS service for running containers. No load balancers, just elastic sizing. No web servers.